# How to reschedule the tasks with their Expiration Time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, quartz-scheduler

Problem state is that: I have `N` tasks and their expiration time is different. Given below is a list of tasks with their start and end time.

```
|---------------------|------------------------------------------|
|      Task Name      |     Start Time/End Time                  |
|---------------------|------------------------------------------|
|          1          | 19-Nov-2019:15:20:25/20-Nov-2019:15:20:25|
|---------------------|------------------------------------------|
|          2            19-Nov-2019:13:11:20/20-Nov-2019:13:11:20|
|---------------------|------------------------------------------|
|          3          | 19-Nov-2019:17:10:20/20-Nov-2019:17:10:20|
|---------------------|------------------------------------------|
|          N          | 19-Nov-2019:15:20:27/20-Nov-2019:15:20:27|
|---------------------|------------------------------------------|
```

I have to reschedule the task when it expires like task 3 expire at **20-Nov-2019:17:10:20** then it should reschedule at same time **20-Nov-2019:17:10:20**